# Passing data to JS file + declaring async attribute in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a javascript file I would like to call using jquery getScript

JavaScript File:

```
https://js.dmtry.com/channel.js#gid:1234;advid:123;pid:12345
```

Jquery Call:

```
$.getScript("https://js.dmtry.com/channel.js#gid:1234;advid:123;pid:12345");
```

When I do this, it doesn't seem that the parameters (gid, advid, pid) are being passed to the javascript file. Do you have any ideas why this is with this implementation and how to fix it? Are there alternate ways to pass the parameters to the javascript file? (I am using the 1.7.4 jquery library.)

Also,  how would I declare the async attribute using jquery?

For example, if I had a script, I could do

```
<script async src="javscript.js">
```

How would this be done if I used the same getScript jquery above?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I am calling the javascript function using this jquery:

$(window).load(function(){ $.getScript("http://js.dmtry.com/channel.js#gid:1234;advid:123;pid:12345") });

could this have something to do with the parameters not passing to the JS file, since the DOM would have been fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking to call this script non-asynchronously (the page should not continue loading until the script has been fetched and parsed).  Try using the below to call your script in this fashion.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: //urlhere,
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        success: function () {
            // all good...
        },
        error: function () {
            throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
        }
    });
```

Once your script is loaded (in the success function of this) you can THEN pass variables to it and work with the script as if it was loaded via any other fashion such as putting a script tag in the head.